# What is AssetAccountDeposit in pallet assets config?

Tags: assets

```rust
/// The amount of funds that must be reserved for a non-provider asset account to be maintained.
#[pallet::constant]
type AssetAccountDeposit: Get<DepositBalanceOf<Self, I>>;
```

I do not understand what this type does. I initially thought it was the amount an account should be able to reserve if it was eligible to receive an asset, but after some experiments it didn't turn out to be the case. What does this parameter do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10382),

> Asset accounts (i.e. the storage of a specific account's balance of a
> specific asset) can now have three reasons for existing: the old two
> (i.e. the asset being "sufficient" or taking up a consumer reference)
> **as well as having a deposit explicitly held for the asset-account**.
> This deposit is placed by using the new touch function and refunded by
> using the new refund function.

Notice the `touch()` function inside the assets pallet:

```rust
/// Create an asset account for non-provider assets.
///
/// A deposit will be taken from the signer account.
///
/// - `origin`: Must be Signed; the signer account must have sufficient funds for a deposit
///   to be taken.
/// - `id`: The identifier of the asset for the account to be created.
///
/// Emits `Touched` event when successful.
#[pallet::call_index(26)]
#[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::mint())]
pub fn touch(origin: OriginFor<T>, id: T::AssetIdParameter) -> DispatchResult {
    let id: T::AssetId = id.into();
    Self::do_touch(id, ensure_signed(origin)?)
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cbd8f1b56fd8ab9af0d9317432cc735264c89d70/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L1481-L1495

And inside the `do_touch()` function, `AssetAccountDeposit` is used:

```rust
/// Creates a account for `who` to hold asset `id` with a zero balance and takes a deposit.
pub(super) fn do_touch(id: T::AssetId, who: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
    ensure!(!Account::<T, I>::contains_key(id, &who), Error::<T, I>::AlreadyExists);
    let deposit = T::AssetAccountDeposit::get();
    let mut details = Asset::<T, I>::get(&id).ok_or(Error::<T, I>::Unknown)?;
    ensure!(details.status == AssetStatus::Live, Error::<T, I>::AssetNotLive);
    let reason = Self::new_account(&who, &mut details, Some(deposit))?;
    T::Currency::reserve(&who, deposit)?;
    Asset::<T, I>::insert(&id, details);
    Account::<T, I>::insert(
        id,
        &who,
        AssetAccountOf::<T, I> {
            balance: Zero::zero(),
            is_frozen: false,
            reason,
            extra: T::Extra::default(),
        },
    );
    Ok(())
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cbd8f1b56fd8ab9af0d9317432cc735264c89d70/frame/assets/src/functions.rs#L298-L318

If you want to learn more about `providers`, `consumers`, and `sufficients`, there is a great doc here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/reference/account-data-structures/#accountinfo

Comment: iiuc does that mean there are normal accounts and then there are asset accounts, and to have an asset account I must either reserve the `AssetAccountDeposit` from my native account and/or own the asset by a mint/transfer?